# SMTP Erorr with SQL SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, smtp

For a couple of month we have been sending reports to about 100 users.
We recently enabled MFA on our Office365 Tenant. I added the user sending reports to exceptions. But now the service only sends about 60 of the 100 emails. I have looked into the logs and cant find what the problem actually is.

I have added the error message below.

Than you!

```
emailextension!WindowsService_12!8850!01/03/2022-06:45:12:: e ERROR: Error sending email. Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The server committed a protocol violation The server response was: 
   at System.Net.Mail.SendMailAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendMailCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.EmailDeliveryProvider.EmailProvider.Deliver(Notification notification)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The server committed a protocol violation The server response was: 
   at System.Net.Mail.SendMailAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendMailCallback(IAsyncResult result)<---
. Additional Information: SmtpException StatusCode:GeneralFailure
notification!WindowsService_12!8850!01/03/2022-06:45:12:: e ERROR: Error occurred processing subscription bb732977-1cb9-4fef-8201-193e0e8b20b8: Failure sending mail: One or more errors occurred.Mail will not be resent.
```

Comment: Possibly it's hitting [SmtpClient.Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.timeout)'s default 100,000ms (100sec) setting. How many seconds had passed from the previous emailextension log entries?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Anyone find a resolution yet?

Comment: @jvdeblois I am experiencing the same issue. Have you found a resolution yet?

Answer (score 2):

I actually found the solution. For some reason part of the emails were being sent using TLS 1.0 and the rest were using TLS 1.2 I disabled TLS 1.0 through the registry and it went back to normal.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me as well. 

I also had to add these settings.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001